# Cheat exclusive access locked files in Windows (7)

Tags: windows, file-io

I am currently on a mission loading files into pagecache, and I want to load locked files, too. The goal is nothing more than pro-actively keeping a dataset in RAM, reducing loading times within third party applications.

Shadow copies were my first thought on this, but unfortunately seem to have separated pagecaches.

So is there any way cheating around the exclusive lock mechanism? Like fetching file fragment location on disk, accessing whole disk and reading directly (which I fear is another separated pagecache, anyways)?

Or is there a very different approach to directing the pagecache, e.g. some Windows API that can be told to load a specific file into pagecache?

Comment: If the file's locked already, doesn't that imply that the 3rd party application is running and therefore doesn't need any help starting?

Comment: Take a large database file for example. It is open and locked exclusively, because the DB app is the only one expected to a) write to the file and b) have a consistent view on the file. Also, exclusive lock easily prevents accidents with multiple instances. *But* the DB app will not read the whole file, only necessary parts and indices. I want to "help" the app by reading all data into pagecache.

Comment: What makes you think you can "help" the program more than the OS can?

Comment: OS won't dare to increase read-ahead to several gigabytes :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access locked files in Windows from kernel-mode driver, or using our RawDisk product. But for your task (speed up DB file access) this won't work right as Windows' filesystem cache size is limited (it won't accommodate GBs of data).

In general, if I were to develop a large software project (for small application the amount of work needed is just enormous) I'd do the following: create a virtual drive backed by in-memory storage, present the DB file to the application via that virtual disk and flush drive contents to the disk on change asynchronously. All of this should be done in kernel mode (this is where development time grows to 12-15 man-months of work).

In theory the same can be done using one of our Virtual Storage products, but going back into user mode for callback handling would eliminate all that you gain from moving the data into RAM.